# Digit-avoiding triangles

Tags: combinatorics

This question is a variant of an idea Eric Angelini posted [on his personal blog](http://cinquantesignes.blogspot.com/2020/06/du-recuit-simule.html) and on the math-fun list. It is about finding minimal "digit-avoiding triangles" as I would call it. This means a, say, upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix of distinct positive numbers such that no two entries in the same row or column have a common digit when the numbers are written in base $n+1$. (This means no digits > n, but n > 9 if we wish.) The zero entries are ignored or considered to have no digit; the nonzero numbers may have digits 0, but not two in the same row or column.) For example, a minimal solution for $n=4$ is
$$
\matrix{1 & 2 & 30 & 4\\& 10 & 22 & 3\\&& 14 & 20\\&&& 11} \qquad\text{where all numbers are written in base 5.}
$$
"Minimal" refers a priori to the sum of all numbers, but one might consider other and/or additional criteria, for example, lexicographical order.

A trivial but non-minimal solution is to fill the diagonals with repdigits, but obviously one can do much better: at least n-1 entries ≥ n can be replaced by a smaller number using digits '0'. Also, as illustrated by the '14' in the above example, some larger repdigits can be replaced by a smaller number using digits not in the same row or column.

Is this a known problem? Does anyone know about related investigations?

Is there some theory already developed that might apply to this problem?

Would someone be interested to write an efficient program for an exhaustive search?
(One can imagine a DFS with pruning ("early" backtracking) based on "hand made" near-minimal solutions... To get these one can mix top-down and a bottom-up approaches, where I mean by bottom the base of the triangle, i.e., the diagonal of the square matrix. One can also use digit permutations on "locally minimal solutions" to try to find better ones.)

I proposed the OEIS sequence [A332081](http://oeis.org/A332081) for the list of minimal sums. It refers to another sequence with corresponding minimal triangles. But for the moment, even the n=6 case is not completely settled yet.

Comment: Interesting question.